# show complete action using dialog during download newr version android

Tags: android

I want to update my application programmatically. after i run my application , during download "complete action using" dialog appears. i do not know what is the reason .my code is below :

```
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (downloadReference == referenceId) {

            try{
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Downloading of the new app version complete");
            // start the installation of the latest version
            Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);


             intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");


            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(installIntent);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            String mess=    ex.getMessage();
            String a=mess;
            }

        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any intent filters please add them using the tag

`<intent-filter>`